# how to save list of Variable-length list into a single row of CSV and read it as Tensor in tensorflow?

Tags: python, csv, tensorflow

for some reason I have to save data without other python library such as pandas and numpy, then I need to load data in tensorflow. here is the data format and code example.

> ```
> Note that the length of 'xref' and 'asm' is uncertain and this triplet is just one sample in my dataset
> ```

```
file_paths = ['1.csv']
ea = 1                          # int32
xref = [1,2]                    # N-list int32
asm = [[4,5,6,7,8],[9,0,1,2,3]] # Mx5-list float32
with open('1.csv','w') as f:
    csv_f = csv.writer(f)
    csv_f.writerow((ea,xref,asm))
# CSV file:
# 1,"[1, 2]","[[4, 5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 0, 1, 2, 3]]"

#loading
dataset = tf.data.TextLineDataset(file_paths)
for textline in dataset:
    record_default = [0,'0','0']        
    ea,xref,asm = tf.io.decode_csv(textline,record_defaults=record_default)
```

the data loaded as follow:

> <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=1>

> <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=string, numpy=b'[1, 2]'>

> <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=string, numpy=b'[[4, 5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 0, 1, 2, 3]]'>

it still far from my target which data should be loaded like

> <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=1>

> <tf.Tensor: shape=(2,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([1, 2])>

> <tf.Tensor: shape=(2, 5), dtype=float32, numpy= array([[4, 5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 0, 1, 2, 3]])>

So what can I do? Actually I want to use *dataset.map(func)*,I tried json format,it works but is too slow for tensorflow.